# jQueryUI show/hide animation issue with child nodes

Tags: css, jquery-ui, show-hide

I'm having trouble with the show()/hide() function of jQueryUI. They basically deactivate my CSS for the duration of the animation.

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/UBATE/1/

According to the API:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Drop,

I've built the following function:

```
updateTeamLists = function(args) {
    // fade out -> rebuild the content -> fade in

    $("#team1, #team2").hide("drop", {"direction": "right"}, 600, function() {
        rebuildTeamLists(args); 
        $(this).show("drop", {"direction": "right"}, 600);  
    });     
};
```

The child DOM nodes appear to lose all their CSS attributes in the beginning of the animation, i.e. they stop floating (or lose their inline-block display) and their backgrounds vanish instantly. However, the animation and the fading out of the text work fine.

HTML DOM structure:

```
<div id="teams">
   <div id="team1">
      <ul>
         <li>Player 1</li>
         <li>Player 2</li>
         <li>Player 3</li>
         <li>Player 4</li>
         <li>0 Pts</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="team2">
      <ul>
         <li>Player 5</li>
         <li>Player 6</li>
         <li>Player 7</li>
         <li>Player 8</li>
         <li>0 Pts</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content > #teams {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 22px;
    width: 650px;
    border: 2px solid #bfbfbf;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#content > #teams > div {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
}

#content > #teams > div:first-child {
    opacity: 1.0;   
}

#content > #teams > div:last-child {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

#content > #teams > div > ul > li {
    height: 25px;
    width: 125px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: 5px;   
    display: inline-block;
}

#content > #teams > div > ul > li:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

#content > #teams > div > ul > li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;

    width: 50px !important;
}

#content > #teams > #team1 > ul > li {
    background: rgb(229,130,130); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229,130,130) 0%, rgb(216,43,43) 51%, rgb(232,153,153) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgb(229,130,130)), color-stop(51%,rgb(216,43,43)), color-stop(100%,rgb(232,153,153))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229,130,130) 0%,rgb(216,43,43) 51%,rgb(232,153,153) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229,130,130) 0%,rgb(216,43,43) 51%,rgb(232,153,153) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(229,130,130) 0%,rgb(216,43,43) 51%,rgb(232,153,153) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(229,130,130) 0%,rgb(216,43,43) 51%,rgb(232,153,153) 100%); /* W3C */
    border-color: rgb(229,130,130);

    text-align: center;
    padding-top:3px;
}

#content > #teams > #team2 > ul > li {
    background: #b3dced; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%, #29b8e5 50%, #bce0ee 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#b3dced), color-stop(50%,#29b8e5), color-stop(100%,#bce0ee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%,#29b8e5 50%,#bce0ee 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%,#29b8e5 50%,#bce0ee 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%,#29b8e5 50%,#bce0ee 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #b3dced 0%,#29b8e5 50%,#bce0ee 100%); /* W3C */
    border-color: rgb(179,220,237);

    text-align: center;
    padding-top:3px;
}
```

Unfortunately I can't host the code online for a demo so I've posted up anything I got. I'm using Google Chrome 17.0.963.56 and Firefox 10.0.2.

I'm quite often having trouble with adding jQueryUI effects to my scripts, ending up not adding them. Though there might be some tricks/bugs preventing it from working (e.g. if your DOM node didn't have a class attribute, toggleClass animations wouldn't work).

Did I miss something? How would a workaround look like, would I have to iterate through all the child nodes?

Thanks in advance!

Harti

Comment: Can you create an example at http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/UBATE/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery UI will add an extra div under the effected element. Example:

```
<div id="team1">
<ul>
  ...
<ul>
</div>
```

When the effect is applying, the structure will be:

```
<div id="team1">
<div class="jquery-ui something-else">
<ul>
  ...
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The solution is not to use the direct-child selector ">". See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhgb/UBATE/9/). You can compare it with your version :)

Comment: Thanks, this is going to help for the moment. There is a little y-offset issue with your solution but it can be fixed by editing the "#content > #teams div" line. However, when I change it to "#content > #teams #team1, #content > #teams #team2", the margin-top will disappear. I'm not really new to CSS but still really confused...

Also I'm afraid I somehow overwrote your helpful fiddle. You can find it now under: http://jsfiddle.net/UBATE/12/

And this is what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/3NHSR/

Comment: I think it's because you've add a comma by mistake :) `#teams #team1, 
#teams #team2, {`

Comment: Firebug or chrome's development tool can be very useful when writing css

Comment: The typo was not the problem, but I sorted the problem out by replacing margin-top with margin-bottom so the jqueryUI div won't affect the design.

Comment: Doesn't it in fact insert the extra div **around** the effected element? My testing indicates this..